# Fail to get table from web

Tags: r, rvest

I try to get the second table of http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/Results/chinese/Local/20171105/ST/2

by using rvest.

Here is my code:

```
url <-"http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/Results/chinese/Local/20171105/ST/2"

webpage <- read_html(url)
```

However, webpage get

```
node:<externalptr> , doc:<externalptr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

url <- "http://racing.hkjc.com/racing/info/meeting/Results/chinese/Local/20171105/ST/2"
web_table <- read_html(url) %>%
  html_nodes('table') %>%
  .[19] %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
web_table <- web_table[[1]]
web_table
```